# websites for mobile apps

Tags: css, mobile

I'm developing a website for mobile phones (mostly Blackberry).

I can't figure out how one develops like this. Some phones don;t support CSS. If I want a button with an up and a down state, how do I do it? I'd usually make an anchor, then put the image in the background, then I could control the background position with pseudo classes link and active.

```
<a id="btnSearch"></a>

#btnSearch{
    height:     16px;
    overflow:       hidden;
    background-image:   url(img/btnSearch.png);
}
#btnSearch:link,
#btnSearch:visited,
#btnSearch:hover{
    background-position:0 0;
}
#btnSearch:active{
    background-position:0 -16px;
}
```

but I can't do this because some mobile devices will show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if they don't support CSS, then you obviously can't get button effects such as those you describe. The best you can do is provide alternate text within the anchor:

```
<a id="btnSearch"><span>some text</span></a>
```

and hide that text in browsers that do support CSS:

```
#btnSearch > span {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: But what is Best Practice for website development for mobile apps?

Comment: @DaveC426913: Most of the mainstream mobile browsers support CSS, so you don't have to worry too much. If you would also like to support really old browsers that don't, you can use alternatives like I suggested above.